# After update, audio won't play through HDMI cable

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, hdmi

Yesterday (June 7th) I faithfully updated a bunch of stuff through update manager (though I'm not sure what since I never read what I updated any more because I'm a *bad person*). Afterward, I discovered that I could no longer play audio through my tv via HDMI.  The sound settings menu seems to have completely changed and the shell script that I wrote a week ago (with much **pain** and **effort** as I had never before written a shell script) to toggle between my laptop speakers and the HDMI cable output no longer works.  When I type in

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-surround
```

in the command line I get

```
Failure: No such entity
```

Presumably this means something with Pulse Audio changed but, while I'm learning a lot about the inner workings of Ubuntu/Linux, I'm not an expert and would love some help.

EDIT:  So I noticed that

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

seems to get everything working, so the name of the hdmi output just changed.  Still, shouldn't there be a way to switch to HDMI through the GUI as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try installing pavucontrol by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

or via Ubuntu Software Center [image: Install via the software center]

After installation, you should be able to configure your audio device with this gui.

For reference see also http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Passthrough

Comment: Don't mention it, I'm glad if I was of any help. I was reading about this on Google+ the other day and thought it was worth sharing :) Have fun!

Comment: You can also get a graphical tool for this same things. Install it with `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer` command.

Comment: Pavucontrol _is_ a graphical tool, but for configuration of pulse audio, while alsamixer, as the name implies, is a configuration tool for alsa audio.