# No options for sound output

Tags: sound, hdmi

Newbie here.  Trying out Ubuntu for kicks.

I have a 10.04 Ubuntu system dual booting on my Windows 7 laptop, fully updated, an Asus A53S.  I have an external Samsung monitor/tv hooked up via HDMI.

I'm getting sound from the external monitor fine when using Win7 but can't get anything with Ubuntu.

I've read threads here about similar stuff and they say go check my sound options but I don't have any additional options than the one listed - Internal Audio.

What else can I check/do?

Comment: I would try a newer release for better support.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148636/after-update-audio-wont-play-through-hdmi-cable/148651#148651) for example. Pavucontrol is a gui for pulseaudio that gives you the option to choose which output system to use.
Good luck!

Comment: Just installed it.  HDMI doesn't show up.  Just my internal audio.

Comment: The last tab (labeled 'Configuration') has a profile drop-down menu. You should find your HDMI-setup there. If not, I can only guess that there's a problem with your soundcard driver. Perhaps it's not supported?