# How to get HDMI sound work on a basic 12.04 install?

Tags: 12.04, hdmi

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) and am using it on my TV. The HDMI sound doesn't work.

All I have installed is:

- The preinstalled codecs and other software,
- a KDE game called KsirK,
- Supertuxkart,
- and GIMP 2.8.

I am using a custom built computer, and a LG TV. My processor is Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz dual core, OS is 32-bit, and I have 1.7GB of ram (after having to remove one stick due to failure). I am also running Windows Xp on the computer.

Comment: Have you tried a [search here for 'HDMI'](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=HDMI)? Try a few of the answers and if that does not help please update your question with some specifics.

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148636/after-update-audio-wont-play-through-hdmi-cable/148651#148651

Comment: I have given you my specifics

Comment: When I say specifics I mean 'What troubleshooting steps from similar questions have you taken', and 'How is your issue different from other 'HDMI not working' questions'? I'd like to help you get better answers by adding this info to your question.

Comment: I have tried a terminal command that fixes mp4 playback bug for gstreamer at a website I can't remember. The way my issue is different from the others is that their problems happened after they installed something, where as my problem was right from when ubuntu was installed.

Answer (score 1):

HDMI output is muted by default (at least on my laptop). Open the Sound Settings (click the speaker icon on the top panel to get to the settings). In the Output tab, an HDMI output should appear when the hdmi cable is connected. Select this, then adjust the volume slider at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Tried that before you said. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It may vary depending on your Laptop/PC environment. Some older HW hadn't got audio via HDMI, but SPIDF instead. Like HP DV2700

Comment: computer is about 1 year old and has latest sound card for when it was built. It has worked on a previous Ubuntu version before that Ubuntu crashed. Is also running Windows XP 32-bit. The pc is completely custom. I didn't make it though, my friend did.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the newest Kernel 3.5 from http://www.kernel.org/ (choose the right version, 32 or 64 bit). Reboot and see if that works. I did that with my laptop and fixed my sound problem. If it doesn't work, you can always delete it from the sypnatics package manager, assuming you have installed that from the software center.

Comment: How would an upstream kernel (from kernel.org) have been installed from the Software Center??? Did you use a PPA?

Comment: I agree with Eliah Kagan. What good would downloading the latest kernel do? Surely, if I needed it ubuntu would update it for me.